# is there a way to delete the previous incomplete fetch and start it all over again?

Tags: git, chromium, git-bash, git-fetch, gclient

I was fetching the chromium, using

```
fetch chromium
```

and unluckily my internet went off . So i pressed `ctrl+c` to end the fetching process then, assuming i could start it all over again later when internet comes.
As the internet came, I wrote `fetch chromium` again and it said

Error message shown:
[image]

Will using `gclient sync` solve the problem itself, or is there a way to delete the previous incomplete fetch and start it all over again? If yes, then how?

Comment: Oh my mistake, didn't read everything. The latter command will sync third party libraries and tools while the first one will download the Chromium source code. So as mentioned in that error message, try `gclient sync`. If it doesn't work then start over again

Comment: I did "gclient sync" and left my pc for 3hrs straight bt that was running then so i ended it by pressing "ctrl+c"  :/ ... can u help to delete this previously done incomplete fetch .so that i can re-fetch it freshly ..bcs if i do "fetch --no history chromium " again then it shows the error msg shown in the question above

Comment: That command should take time as Chromium is a big project. Use `gclient sync -f -D`, it will force gclient to sync and remove untracked files

Comment: You appear not to be using `git fetch`, but rather some other `fetch` command.

Comment: Thankyou every1 for ur help, It's sorted now! I did ```rm -rf  chromium``` to delete the previously done incomplete fetch then ```fetch --no history chromium```  - it took almost 3 hrs PS: for anyone doing this in future, make sure you have a very good internet connection before fetching chromium.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resuming the fetch with `gclient sync`, but AFAIK that is not officially supported for incomplete fetches. I have done this successfully in the past, but it may not work for you.

`fetch` or `gclient sync` will take a while, possibly a very long time, as the [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#:%7E:text=Expect%20the%20command%20to%20take%2030%20minutes%20on%20even%20a%20fast%20connection%2C%20and%20many%20hours%20on%20slower%20ones.) indicates:

> Expect the command to take 30 minutes on even a fast connection, and many hours on slower ones.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest and safest bet to to delete the entire chromium directory / repo and pull it all down again.  The drawback is simply how damn long this takes!  Be sure to include the `--no-history` argument when you fetch it!